# 'could not open port COM3' when trying to sends ascii value from python to arduino

Tags: python, arduino, port

I'm fairly new to programming so forgive me if is this is a silly question, but I've been looking for hours for an answer.

So I'm trying to send ASCII value from python to arduino, I'm following a tutorial and the website said to "sends the ascii value of 1 to the serial port (and to the arduino)"

The problem is, even though my Arduino is on COM3, I kept getting this message

```
serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port 'COM3': 
FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)
```

The line is pretty simple,

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial ('COM3', 9600)
```

I really don't get what's wrong?
Any help would be really appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really silly, the tutorial told to code first then assemble the hardware, so I did just that and get this error, but when I tried and connected the Arduino board to my laptop, the code worked perfectly.